# Duffing equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform, differential-equations, dispersion

I have a differential equation: $$\ddot{\omega}+2k\dot{\omega}+2k^2{\omega}-2{\omega}^3=0$$
As I understand it's a [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation), but I can't find the first integral. How can I do it? I didn't find any articles.  $k$ constant.

Answer (score 2):

This is an equation for a damped non-linear oscillator, so it doesn't obey energy conservation. Multiply it by $\dot{\omega}$ one can get:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot{\omega}^2}{2} + k^2\omega^2 - \frac{\omega^4}{2}\right) = -2k\dot{\omega}^2
$$
One usually deals with this equation using Van der Pol method, although it depends on the context. You can find the references in [this article](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.92.050903), particularly the one by Dykman (note however that it contains some typos).